# Equivalent of the Control + F to search text in PDF

Tags: pdf, search, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there in Android an equivalent of the control + F search in texts and OCR PDF? In browser we have "find in page" options. But for PDF I didn't find such option. Is there shortcuts to make such search as we can make with the dashboard in PC?

Comment: It depends on the app you are using to open PDF files.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Google's PDF viewer?  If so, there should be a magnifying glass on the top right where you can search from.

Comment: Fine. Thanks so much. I often use Adobe Acrobat.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215844/equivalent-of-the-control-f#comment276541_215845) that you often use Adobe Acrobat, the app offers the same process as Google's PDF viewer. When reading a document, you must click the magnifier.
[image]

You can then enter the word(s) you are looking for on the document.

[image]